# Rust achievements unlockable

Tags: achievements, rust

I have recently started playin Rust with some friends. The game states that there are several achievements to be gotten. However I have met these criteria multiple times and not gotten the achievement. Reading on some steam post about this. They say these are still locked. But can be unlocked using some sort of achievement hack which is deemed cheating by Steam. The achievements are:

- Place Camp Fire
- Craft Camp Fire
- Collect 100 Wood
- Craft Stone Hatchet
- Collect 100 Stone
- Craft Stone Pickaxe

TLDR: Any clue on how to unlock the achievements for Rust?

Comment: Which achievements, and what are the criteria?

Comment: Added the achievement list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to play on official servers for the achievements to unlock, see following commit https://rust.facepunch.com/commits/2017/July/#21930 which reads "Limit achievements to official servers".

Comment: I went on a official server and tested it just to be sure, worked out. Thanks!

Comment: I went on official US server and it didn't work. Verified game and reinstalled game no progress.

Comment: Most official server don't have steam achievements enabled. Look for servers provided by FacePunch, the developer of Rust.a

Answer (score 2):

In order to unlock the rust achievements you must complete them on official servers.

Apparently there is an option to enable them as a server hoster but I have not seen this option and I personally host one.